# Running kubectl command in Jenkins using a minikube kubernetes cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a jenkins on my http://localhost:8080/ and I created a project which will run a kubectl command to connect to a kubernetes cluster using (minikube)

I'm trying to run a windows command
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test2>kubectl apply -f .\my-deployment.yaml

Here's the minikube cluster info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443

on Jenkins my build environment is like
[image: here's my kubernetes kubectl config in Jenkins]

Is there a default credential when connecting to minikube? I used default-admin with no password or admin/admin

I'm getting this error during Jenkins build

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test2>kubectl apply -f .\my-deployment.yaml 

error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minikube makes use of SSL certificates to connect to the API server. Then you need to use that certificate to properly identify yourself. You can find the information in your `.kube/config` file.

Comment: Thanks Javier, from the .kube/config I used the  equivalent certificate-authority-data: (I think this is the Bas64 converted apiserver.crt from the cluster.